# Jquery add class if have parent with certain class

Tags: parent, addclass

I'm looking to do the following.

If there is a parent div with a class of 'open' then add the class 'on' to an element (the h3)

Jquery

```
$('h3').parent('.open').addClass('on');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get it by going through simple jquery examples. the following snippet will be helpful.

```
$('h3').each(function(){
   if($(this).parent().attr("class")=="open"){
          $(this).attr("class","on")
      }
});
```

The same output can be achieved by the following single line code

```
 $(".open h3").attr('class',"on");
```